# How to scan QR code with multibit wallet application?

Tags: wallet, multibit, qrcode

I downloaded the multibit application for windows and was wondering if there was a way to scan a QR code with my webcam? If so where do I click because I dont see an option and no way am I going to type out an address everytime.

Answer (score 1):

Webcams aren't supported in MultiBit.

You can however paste a QR code using the 'paste' button in the side bar. You can also drag and drop an image onto the existing QR code in the side bar.

Comment: so i have to take a pic of it using an external application then? which ones do you use for windows/linux/mac?